# Does Web application service needs to be running on a server where central admin is hosted?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, spservices

In SharePoint 2010 environment, does Web application service needs to be running on a server where central admin is hosted?

Answer (score 3):

If your SharePoint architecture is for multi farm, then the webapplication service needs to run only on the web servers and your farm will be hosted on Application server.

Suppose you have 3 servers.

- 1 Application server.
- 2 Web Servers.

Your webapplication service should run on the two web servers.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is required to be running in all the servers where web applications are hosted. so central admin is also a iis site so it should be running too.